# How to re-login account by using Google Calendar API?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am developing sync calendar service using [Google Calendar API for .NET](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet)

Here is my code:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "[ClientId].apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "[ClientSecret]",
            },
            new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" },
            "user", 
            CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

It works fine for the first login. When that code is executed, it opens a new login popup window so user can login using their Google account.

The problem is, when user wants to change their account, I don't know how to re-open the login popup window again, because when that code is executed for the second time, it still has the previous account connection and it doesn't open anything.

The question is how to reset the connection of previous account so user can re-login again?

Comment: Try adding `prompt=consent` parameter to the [authentication request](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#sendauthrequest). This will make the consent screen display every time the user logs into your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mr.Rebot . However I am still wondering, is it possible if I pass this `prompt=consent` parameter via `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()`? 
I have tried to find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker, but still got no clue. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but I think you have to use **`GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl`** as stated in this reported issue [#1185](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1185) and [#453](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/453) and add `prompt='consent'` to the url request. I think they've added the prompt property in the auth url.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, in other hand, how to avoid this consent screen? The user of my application need to re-consent every 24 hours (i guess).